# Add \only<>{} and \uncover<>{} sequences in pandoc beamer

Tags: beamer, pandoc, markdown

Most probably my question shall be better addressed to the [pandoc](http://pandoc.org/) developers yet I was wondering if anybody managed to use the `\only<N>{ ... }` (or `\uncover<N>{ ... }`) directives in a pandoc / Beamer environment.

More precisely, I work on [my own beamer theme](https://github.com/Falkor/beamerthemeFalkor) where I try to implement a set of  [markdown](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax)-based slides transformed to LaTeX Beamer using the following command

```
 pandoc –from markdown –to beamer –slide-level 3 -o <filename>.md.tex <filename>.md
```

- See [this example](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Falkor/beamerthemeFalkor/master/examples/markdown/_content_in_markdown.md), the [directory layout](https://github.com/Falkor/beamerthemeFalkor/tree/master/examples/markdown) and the [generated slides in PDF](https://github.com/Falkor/beamerthemeFalkor/blob/master/examples/markdown.pdf)

One trouble is that if I try to add in a frame the `\only<1>{...}` directly,[pandoc](http://pandoc.org/) transform it to the LaTeX sequence `\only\textless{}1\textgreater{}\{...\}`.

To ensure the un-interpreted rendering, one way is to place the `\only<1>{...}` sequence within a given environment between `\begin{...} ... \end{...}`, where [pandoc](http://pandoc.org/) is configured to treat the content as native LaTeX command. One drawback for which I'm searching a workaround, is that you can no longer use the Markdown syntax within the `\only<N>{ ... }` block. 
Ex:

```
* an item in markdown

\begin{flushleft}
  \only<1>{That's fine}
  \only<2>{That's also fine, but I can no longer use the **Markdown** syntax}
\end{flushleft}
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/issues/3184

Comment: @naught101 Would you like to write a short answer that this feature had been implemented in the mean time?

Answer (score 2):

In the mean time the possibility to use `\only<>{}` etc. has been added to `pandoc` in the commit https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/commit/8d7ecc27a19facf6c4b50a65ee1029c105aacdb2